# Declare global string

Tags: angular

I'm new in Angular 5. I create services where I set api rootUrl for all my actions like:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsuariosService {
  readonly rootUrl = "http://myapiurl/";
```

and I use like

```
list() {
    var perfiles = this.http
      .get(this.rootUrl + "api/perfiles/listar", this.options)
      .map((data: any) => data.json());
    return perfiles;
  }
```

I want to know how can I set it globally? In what document should I do it, and how can I import and use it into each service? instead declare it on each one? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have your `rootUrl` available in the whole application, the best option would be to put this field in `environment.ts` file.

Not only you will able to use it in every file, but you can easily change it for different environments ex. `dev` or `prod`

Here you can find more details: [Application Environments](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-application-environments)